# Change src attribute with javascript in asp

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web in ASP and im trying to add a script in JavaScript to modify the src attribute (not to change the image, just to modify the src attribute).

And when I implement it the image of the web disappear.

I directly copy this code in my asp code:

```
document.getElementById ("myelementid").src = "inventedname.jpg";
</script>
```

Comment: Changing the "src" attribute to something different than its original value will change the image.

Comment: When you change the `src` attribute your image is refreshed and a new call goes through the server, so you just *"change the image"*

Comment: Is There anyway to make it look more friendly? Is a google map image generated automatically and the src attribute is a real mess and also has my googe api key